# JavaScript variable being ignored

Tags: javascript, data-structures, linked-list, stack

So I'm trying to write a Data Structures Visualizer with JS (so that I can host it online). It seems as though my JS ignoring my variables (and claiming some functions don't exist) and I can't figure out why. I'd appreciate the help.

```
var stack = new Stack();
var defaultValueCounter = 0;
function push() {
    var value = document.getElementById("add").value;
    if (value === "") {
        defaultValueCounter++;
        value = defaultValueCounter;
    }
    //console.log(stack + ", " + value)
    stack.push(value);
    addCol(value);
    stack.print();
    document.getElementById("add").value = "";
}
```

In that code, it seems to ignore stack for some reason (initializes to undefined). I've tested this hypothesis by moving the declaration inside the push() function, and it works (although for obvious reasons, my Stack can only contain 1 element). What can I do to fix it

Edit: 
Sharing my Stack implementation

```
function Node() {
    this.value;
    this.next ;
}

var Stack= function(){
    this.head;
}

Node.prototype.insert=function(value) {
    var current = this;
    if (current.value === undefined) { //has nothing yet
        current.value = value; //insert here
        return;
    }

    if(current.next === undefined) { //completely null
        current.next = new Node();//want new node
    }
    var c = current.next;
    c.insert(value);
}

Stack.prototype.push= function(value) {
    if(value==undefined || value==""){
        throw "Please input proper value (number)"
    }
    if(this.head==undefined){//nothing exists yet
        this.head=new Node();
        this.head.value=value;
    }else{//nonempty stack
        var c=this.head;
        c.next=new Node();
        c.next=this.head;
        c.value=value;
        this.head=c;
    }   
}


Stack.prototype.top= function() {   
    if(this.head==undefined){//nothing exists yet
        throw "Trying to get top of null"
    }else{//nonempty stack
        return this.head.value;
    }   
}

Stack.prototype.pop= function() {

    if(this.head==undefined){//nothing exists yet
        throw "Trying to get top of null"
    }else{//nonempty stack
        var val=this.head.value;
        this.head=this.head.next;
        return val;
    }   
}

Stack.prototype.print= function(){
    //debugging purposes
    var c=new Node();
    c.value=this.head.value
    c.next=this.head.next
    while(c.value!=undefined){
        console.log(c.value)
        c=c.next
    }
    console.log("Head: "+ this.value)
}
```

Edit: It seems as though the code is not initializing the stack at the beginning. What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Can you share your definition of Stack? From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) > "Creating a user-defined object requires two steps:
> > Define the object type by writing a function. Create an instance of
> the object with new. To define an object type, create a function for
> the object type that specifies its name and properties. An object can
> have a property that is itself another object."

Comment: can you share you Stack implementation

Comment: Done. I'm still not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: your `//nonempty stack` code is overwriting the value of whatever is at this.head ... `c.next=new Node();
        c.next=this.head;` basically just creates a new Node, then totally discards it in the next statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, I resolved all issues by deleting top(). Not sure why. Will investigate my code futher

Answer (score 0):

You perhaps need to use

```
function Stack() {
```

instead of

```
var Stack = function() {
```

as function definitions are hoisted, where as only var declarations, not var definitions are hoisted

This explains why `Stack` is `undefined`

Also, your nonempty stack code should be

```
}else{//nonempty stack
    var c=new Node;
    c.next = this.head;
    c.value=value;
    this.head=c;
}
```

Comment: Does setting c=this.head point them to the same place? I thought it would just copy them over together. If that is the case, is my print code better for copying the value?

Comment: Also the thing still says that Stack DNE

Comment: if `var stack = new Stack();` fails, is the code that defines `Stack` before this code? ... instead of `var Stack= function(){` try `function Stack(){` as function definitions are hoisted whereas only var declarations are hoisted

Answer (score -1):

You have a problem with scope. `stack` is declared outside of the function and not passed to the function. Hence, it is `undefined` when you try to access it.

To fix this, ensure that the method `push()` operates on the `stack` variable by making variable visible to the function.

Comment: the function actually has access to the stack variable because it is attached global scope which is window

Comment: Shouldn't it have access? I read that it any vars declared outside functions are globals.

Comment: it's not really a scope issue, it's the difference between function and variable hoisting in javascript

Comment: If it is attached to the window, then it must be defined as long as callee has the same scope. @pasha How do you call `push` function?

Comment: A button click. As stated I'm not sure why, but removing top fixed everything