# JavaScript ignoring function that exists

Tags: javascript, scope, stack

I'm trying to write a JS data structure visualization. The Stack is giving me weird pains. The code:

```
function pop() {
    //stack=new Stack();
    setTimeout(function () {
        try {
            var value = stack.pop();
            console.log(stack+", "+value);
            removeCol(value);
        } catch (e) {
            showMessage("#status", "Underflow", "red")
        }
    }, 200)
}
...
function showMessage(id, html, color) {
    $(id).html(html);
    $(id).css("color", color);
}
```

seems to thing that showMessage DNE. This is even though I have written it out here. This is one of the issues I'm having with JS (another linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61857251/javascript-variable-being-ignored). I don't quite understand what I'm doing wrong. Should I just give up on the thing, and use another language/tool? I'm open to suggestions. What's with JS scopes anyway?

Comment: your other question has nothing to do with scopes ... and this should not either ... if those two functions are in the global scope in the same file (no ES6 import involved) then showMessage is definitely defined

Comment: Code is working, see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tmg8uso0/

Comment: I thought that they were both problems with scopes because the code was saying the stack did not exist in the other one, and function DNE in this.